# Second monitor with laptop doesn't go to full resolution

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a Dell Latitude D520 with Intel 945GM chipset on board and WinXP. I started working with an external monitor a while ago (Gateway EV910). Initially everything seemed to work ok, and I was able to set the monitor to use its max resolution (I think it was 1200*1600). But then I stared getting blue screens whenever I connected the monitor. So I downloaded from Dell the newest driver for the Intel chipset. This stabilized the system. But now the monitor won't go beyond 1024*768 and it won't do more the 60Hz refresh rate (very annoying).

I searched online for the monitor driver but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another hint might be, that the monitor listed as connected is "default monitor". As I mentioned I wanted to get the official driver for the Gateway EV910, hopping that this will force the laptop to recognize the real hardware capabilities of this monitor. But I couldn't find this driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you setting the Display Properties?

On my laptop with an Intel chipset running XP I find if I use the standard Windows Display Properties multiple monitors never quite work properly.  When I use the Intel settings dialog everything works fine.

You can get to the Intel dialog one of the following ways:

- Open Windows Display Properties, select the Settings tab, click the Advanced button, select the Intel tab and click the Graphics Properties button.
- If have the Intel Adapter Icon in the System Tray you can right-click it and select Graphics Properties.

Comment: I was looking at the Intel dialog. It has the same limitations (1024*768) as the XP one.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify you installed the correct drivers for 945GM, not 945M or something similar. It could also be a limitation set by Dell. Unfortunately I don't know if there's any way to verify this unless it's in the release notes for the driver.

I know some Intel video sets have limited resolution capabilities. It could be tied to how much memory is allocated for video.

Comment: The thing is I know for a fact the hardware supports higher resolution. Because I had it running at 1600*1200 before I updated the driver

Comment: I was thinking the blue screens could be caused by the old driver not limiting resolution like it should, but that's why I said to verify that the new driver isn't locked at 1024x768 and that it's the correct driver. I know some of the driver download sites can be confusing.